# Работа с геоданными

Tags: геометрия, геолокация, yandex-geocoding-api, geocoding

Есть такая задача: разделить город(Москву) на части как пиццу и по координатам точки определять к какой части города(пиццы) относиться эта точка точка. Не совсем понятно как это реализовать.
Задача выполняется на бекенде и пользователю не имеет отношения.
Сложность в том что, я не смог разобраться как работать с геоданными. Как я понимаю широту и долготу нужно перевести в какую нибудь плоскую систему координат, и уже на плоскости решать задачу. Не понятно в какую систему координат перевести и как перевести.

Comment: необходимо описать эти полигоны точками и проверять принадлежность точки к полигону при помощи какой нибудь библиотеки по работе с геоданными, например в js это можно сделать при помощи tirf.js - https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-inside

Comment: для бэкэнда есть например jts - java topology suite https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite